# Enabling a Feature via Drush

Tags: drupal, drush

When I enable a Feature through the site UI, everything goes as expected.

However, when I enable a feature from drush with `drush pm-enable`, the following don't happen:

- Strongarm configurations not applied
- module_disable (in a new custom
  module) not performed

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had a conflict in two Features. Fine now.